# Utilities.formatDate - incorrect year in the formatted string

Tags: google-apps-script, simpledateformat, date-formatting

In Google App Script consider the following date formatting code

```
function testDateFormatter(){
         // Sun Dec 31 2017 20:02:06
         var date = new Date(1514746926811)
         var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, "CET", "YYYY-MM-dd");    
         Logger.log("The date is : " + date + ", after formatting it is "  + dateString) 
    }
```

The  result is:

```
//
// The date is : Sun Dec 31 2017 20:02:06 GMT+0100 (CET), after formatting it is 2018-12-31
//
```

**note 2018 instead of 2017 !!!!**

Why GAS added the whole year to the date?

With other sample dates it works fine i.e.:

```
var date = new Date(1511377747255)
var dateString = Utilities.formatDate(date, "CET", "YYYY-MM-dd");    
Logger.log("The date is : " + date + ", after formatting it is "  + dateString) 
//
// Logger: The date is : Wed Nov 22 2017 20:09:07 GMT+0100 (CET), after formatting it is 2017-11-22
//
```

Comment: Use `yyyy` to get calendar year, per [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: it is so easy to miss between YYYY and yyyy - the type of error the will activate only few days a year.
yyyy - the year of the actual date
YYYY - the year of the #week (and for week 52 the year may still be the previous year even a data is in the new year....

Answer (score -2):

I don't see the problem:

```
function myFunction() {
  var dt=new Date(1514746926811);
  var dts=Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")//not YYYY
  Logger.log('dt=%s dts=%s',dt,dts);
}
```

Logger Output is:

[17-12-22 15:17:07:058 MST] dt=Sun Dec 31 12:02:06 GMT-07:00 2017 dts=12/31/2017 12:02:06

Comment: The problem is clearly stated in the question; you have copied the example that the OP called "works fine"

Comment: Okay.  I changed the date value.  But the answer is still the same.  I  don't see the problem.

Comment: Because your code is different from OP's code, of course.

Comment: It's a subtle difference and I didn't notice until I looked at it the second time.